# Check if module is already imported before doing async import()

Tags: javascript, import

I am creating a lazy loaded component. My question is about JavaScript itself, not any specific framework (React, Svelte, etc), so I'm showing some pseudocode.

```
const myLazyLoadedComponent() {

  let myComponent
  let isLoading = true
  import('/some/path.xx').then(c => {
    myComponent = c
    isLoading = false
  })

//this part is reactive with the variables above:

  return (
    if (isLoading) <div>Loading..<div/>
    else <myComponent/>
  )
}
```

This will work well the first time. But when I would close-reopen or open another instance of it, the `Loading..` would show for a microsecond before the myComponent.

**Is there a way to first check if the module was already imported, and based on that, either use it directly or async import()?**

Something like this:

```
if (isAlreadyImported('/some/path.xx').) {
  import { myComponent } from '/some/path.xx'
} else {
  isLoading = true
  import('/some/path.xx').then(c => {
    myComponent = c
    isLoading = false
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could cache your components and execute a callback either sync or async:

```
const cache = {};
async function loadComponent(loader, cb){
   const key = loader.toString();
   if(cache[key]){
      cb(cache[key]);
      return cache[key];
   }
   cache[key] = await loader().then(m => m.default);
   cb(cache[key]);
   return cache[key];
}

...

isLoading = true;
await loadComponent(() => import('/some/path.xx'), c => (isLoading = false, myComponent = c));
```